# error - ./node_modules/busboy/lib/main.js:1:0 Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, next.js, apollo

When I add a new React component to my NextJS app (React, TypeScript and GraphQL), my local development environment suddenly breaks with this cryptic error:

```
wait  - compiling...
error - ./node_modules/busboy/lib/main.js:1:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'
null
```

When I stash my new component, everything works fine. I'm trying to figure out what it is in my new component that's triggering this error.

Relevant dependencies:

- @apollo/client: ^3.2.5
- apollo-server-micro: ^2.18.2
- graphql: ^15.4.0
- next: 10.0.0
- react: 17.0.1
- react-dom: 17.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was importing `gql` from the wrong package. As I'm building both the server and the client in one app, I have to be careful importing the right methods from the right packages.

This line from my imports caused the error:

`import { gql } from "apollo-micro-server`

Changing the line to this fixed the error:

`import { gql } from "@apollo/client"`